# Fileinfo `failed identify data 0` error in PHP 7.1

Tags: php

I am trying to get a directory lister running on my server.

The code I use is simple:

```
$fi = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

if (! file_exists($filePath)) {
    return false;
}

$type = $fi->file($filePath);
```

Whatever filepath I try, it keeps throwing an error:

> PHP Warning:  finfo::file(): Failed identify data 0:cannot happen:
>   invalid relation `@' in

I have tried the following things:

1. Test the `file` command, this works fine and returns the right mime type
2. Tried using `finfo` functions instead of class, same result (of course)
3. Tried various of files with different content, txt/php/javascript/json/html

None of the above changed the error message...

Any idea how to fix this?

---

I have the following software versions:

- OS: FreeBSD 10.3
- PHP: 7.1.4
- fileinfo.dll: php71-fileinfo version 1.0.5
- Apache: 2.4.23 (FreeBSD)

Comment: Missiming the mime types DB? Play with second arg of finfo ctor? Specifically a bad `MAGIC` env variable?

Comment: Can you fread the file?

Comment: @ficuscr the getenv('MAGIC') returns false

Comment: @Sebas Yes I can fopen and fread ('r') the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah Windows... Yes, My guess is you do not have the needed database of mime types.

Try `var_dump getenv('MAGIC');`

See [finfo_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php)

> Note:
>   Generally, using the bundled magic database (by leaving magic_file and the MAGIC environment variables unset) is the best course of action unless you specifically need a custom magic database.

Here is one source for that data: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Or, in WAMP try looking at: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apacheX.X.X\conf\mime.types

--

**Update**

I assume the code in PHP from *[libmagic](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=libmagic&sektion=3)* isn't updated as often as the flat file "db" listing extensions to mime types. I've never been very clear how robust the byte sequences detection is or how exactly it all works. I've always considered detecting mime type as a best guess. Would be good [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/fileinfo/libmagic) to look at to try and get a better understanding.

I also don't have a clear understanding of the difference between `FILEINFO_MIME` and `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE` Fileinfo constants. The OOP functions vs the procedural, like `mime_content_type()` is also a little confusing without mentions in the docs. Docs in general are not great on these functions. At one time they incorrectly listed `mime_content_type()` as depreciated which caused a lot of confusion.

Comment: Ah Windows? I have the system OS in the bottom of the post: FreeBSD. The MAGIC ENV variable returns false, so I guess you are right. I don't understand the apache mime.types file though. Do I need to use that instead of finfo to match file extensions with? I would rather fix the magic library?

Comment: Sorry was probably multitasking and read wrong. Windows fits because of unusual apache installs. Anyway, the finfo function depends on that text file for it to detect the mime types. "Returns the MIME content type for a file as determined by using information from the magic.mime file." The web server typically provides the knowledge of what mime type corresponds to what file extension. Maybe thought to be more current? Dunno.

Comment: Well OP did mention a DLL tho, which I don't think works in any linux system

Comment: Thanks Sebas. That is what I saw.